# Пресловутый mysqli_fetch_assoc() в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Знаю, что много уже написано на тему ошибок с mysqli_fetch_assoc()
Но вот снова...
В ВП пытаюсь вывести массив в таблицу из БД
Код простенький:

```
<?php
...
global $wpdb;
$truck = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
if ($truck) {
    echo 
    '<table class="table">' .
        '<thead>' .
        '<tr>' .
        '<th>Имя</th>' .
        // другие заголовки
        '</thead>'; 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($truck)) {
        echo '<tr>' .
        '<td>' . $row['truck_name'] . '</td>' .
        // другие строки
        '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    mysqli_free_result($truck);   
 }
?>
```

Получаю "**Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in**..."

При этом

```
$my_array=array($truck);
foreach($my_array as $myarr)
{
  print_r ($myarr) ."<br />";
}
```

массив выводит. Что не так?

Comment: Не так то что get_results уже возвращает массив, Вам нужно просто пройтись foreach . И не использовать mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам этот fetch не нужен вообще. `get_results()`возвращает массив объектов. Работать с ним надо так:

```
$rows = get_results(...);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->truck_name;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Через foreach вывести не проблема - хотелось разобраться, что с примером не так: вроде все соответствует Кодексу ВП, а не хочет. Грустно

Comment: Где в кодексе вы нашли такой пример? Я сильно сомневаюсь, что там могут советовать такое.